# Android, http post response like xml file

Tags: xml, http, post, response

I have an android application and there is an option for sending HTTP POST REQUEST to my php web server. The post request contains query string for selecting of some data from database in web server.

---

**So my steps are following:**

1. I am going to send query string to web server for receiving some data from database
2. The query string is sended within HTTP POST REQUEST to web server
3. web server will receive such REQUEST and it will select needed data and finally will parse into xml result
4. web server will echo xml result which is actually response for client
5. client will receive response like xml result.

---

Echo xml result

```
$file_xml = db_select_into_xml($query, $file_path);
echo $file_xml;
```

---

**There are following problems:**

1. When I used normal java program for testing it then it works. I will receive xml response.
2. But when I used android program for testing it then it does not work. I will receive xml response but not whole xml response. I do not know where is the problem. The xml file is not parsed like whole file. I will receive only part of xml file, specifically only header.

I am using this code sketch for my purposes regarding HTTP REQUEST.

> This is only sketch (with errors) which is very similar my code. Sorry
>   but I will add my code as I will be home.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);

con.getOutputStream().write( ( <MY QUERY> ).getBytes());
con.connect();

InputStream is = 
con.getInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ( is.read(b) != -1) {
buffer.append(new String(b));
}
con.disconnect();

//buffer contains the xml result
```